# Converting different date time formats to MM/DD/YYYY format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a date column in a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) in various date time formats and stored as list object, like the following:

```
            date
1    [May 23rd, 2011]
2    [January 1st, 2010]
    ...
99   [Apr. 15, 2008]
100  [07-11-2013]
    ...
256  [9/01/1995]
257  [04/15/2000]
258  [11/22/68]
    ...
360  [12/1997]
361  [08/2002]
     ...
463  [2014]
464  [2016]
```

For the sake of convenience, I want to convert them all to `MM/DD/YYYY` format. It doesn't seem possible to use regex replace() function to do this, since one cannot execute this operation over list objects. Also, to use strptime() for each cell will be too time-consuming.

What will be the easier way to convert them all to the desired `MM/DD/YYYY` format? I found it very hard to do this on list objects within a dataframe.

Note: for cell values of the form `[YYYY]` (e.g., `[2014]` and `[2016]`), I will assume they are the first day of that year (i.e., January 1, 1968) and for cell values such as `[08/2002]` (or `[8/2002]`), I will assume they the first day of the month of that year (i.e., August 1, 2002).

Comment: why would strptime() for each cell will be too time-consuming?  how large is your list?  Doesn't it only need to run once?

Comment: How close do you get with just `pd.to_datetime(df.date)`?

Comment: My dataframe is only about 500 rows. It's manageable, but there are certainly better ways to convert all these formats in one go.

Comment: It says "<class 'list'> is not convertible to datetime" when I applied pd.to_datetime(df.date) because each row in the dataframe is a list object.

Comment: Does `df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))` work?

Comment: No, it does not work. It says "NaTType does not support strftime."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your sample data, with the addition of a `NaT`, this works:

#### Code:

```
df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')[0])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [['']],
    [['May 23rd, 2011']],
    [['January 1st, 2010']],
    [['Apr. 15, 2008']],
    [['07-11-2013']],
    [['9/01/1995']],
    [['04/15/2000']],
    [['11/22/68']],
    [['12/1997']],
    [['08/2002']],
    [['2014']],
    [['2016']],
], columns=['date'])

df['clean_date'] = df.date.apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')[0])

print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
                   date  clean_date
0                    []         NaT
1      [May 23rd, 2011]  05/23/2011
2   [January 1st, 2010]  01/01/2010
3       [Apr. 15, 2008]  04/15/2008
4          [07-11-2013]  07/11/2013
5           [9/01/1995]  09/01/1995
6          [04/15/2000]  04/15/2000
7            [11/22/68]  11/22/1968
8             [12/1997]  12/01/1997
9             [08/2002]  08/01/2002
10               [2014]  01/01/2014
11               [2016]  01/01/2016
```

Comment: Thanks for helping on this. I suppose this solves my problem, although I could not apply this really straightforward code to my own data (the data is a pandas series contains hundred of list objects like the one shown in the example data). I thought I could have converted that to dataframe and apply you code, but it says 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_DataFrame'

Comment: So this code works on a panda.Series of lists, each list only having one item.  The expression `df.date.apply` does an apply to the Series which is in the column `date`.  If you have only a Series and not a DataFrame you can should be able to do `my_series.apply(....)`.

Comment: Yes, this code does work on pandas dataframe with list objects. I am trying to think of a way to convert my series object to dataframe, so that I can apply your code. When I used my_series.apply(), I got this following error message "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Comment: You do not need to convert.  In fact this code converts the column of a DataFrame to a Series.  That is what `df.date` does.  If takes one column named `date` and makes it a series.  So as I tried to indicate in my previous comment, take this code, and change `df.date` to be the name of your Series.  Should just work.

Comment: Yes, I did, but I received the same error message "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0."

Comment: Well it appears that there is something else non-uniform about the data in your Series.

Comment: I couldn't solve it. The dataset just doesn't make much sense to me. But the original data series does look every bit like the example data shown in this thread.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti, I just tested with that string and it works fine for me.  I got `08/24/2014`

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you it worked finally with me. not sure what was the problem!!

Comment: @Stephen Rauch. This one works great. how we can apply same function to date columns of same dataframe. for example; process_date & order_date. Do we need to specify or call this lambda function twice?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you use this it'll give you the date format in MM-DD-YYYY the you can apply strftime:

```
df['Date_ColumnName'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_ColumnName'], dayfirst = False, yearfirst = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided code will work for following scenarios.

- Change date format from M/D/YY to MM/DD/YY (5/2/2009 to 05/02/2009)
- change form ANY FORMAT to MM/DD/YY

import pandas as pd

```
'''
       * checking provided input file date format correct or not
       * if format is correct change date format from M/D/YY to MM/DD/YY
       * else date format is not correct in input file
         Date format  change form ANY FORMAT to MM/DD/YY
  '''
input_file_name = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/SarenderReddy/predictions.csv'
dest_file_name = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/SarenderReddy/Enrich.csv'
#input_file_name = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/SarenderReddy/enrichment.csv'
read_data = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)
print(pd.to_datetime(read_data['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce').notnull().all())

if pd.to_datetime(read_data['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce').notnull().all():
    print("Provided correct input date format in input file....!")
    read_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(read_data['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
    read_data['Date'] = read_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    read_data.to_csv(dest_file_name,index=False)
    print(read_data['Date'])
else:
    print("NOT... Provided correct input date format in input file....!")
    data_format = pd.read_csv(input_file_name,parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
    #print(df['Date'])
    data_format['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_format['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
    data_format['Date'] = data_format['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    data_format.to_csv(dest_file_name,index=False)
    print(data_format['Date'])
```